# Having Tkinter's after() return output in order of time called

Tags: python, logging, tkinter

I am writing a program to log some measurements. To log every second, I am using `after()` at the end of the logging function `log()` to recall it. Is this creating a recursion and therefore not returning the logs in order of time? (Also printing more than 1 log per second) How can I make sure that each entry is in order of time with 1 log per second?

Here is some of my code:

```
 def log(self):

    if self.running ==True:

        self.current_date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.current_time = datetime.time(now.hour, now.minute, now.second)

        if self.boolvars[0].get() == True:
            self.t = self.t + str(self.current_date) + ", "
        if self.boolvars[1].get() == True:
            self.t = self.t  + str(self.current_time) + ", "
        if self.boolvars[2].get() == True:
            self.t = self.t + str(self.mic.VacGetPressure(0)) + ", "
            self.champres.append(str(self.mic.VacGetPressure(0)))
        if self.boolvars[3].get() == True:

       ...
       ...
       ...

        self.screen.insert(INSERT, self.t)
        self.parent.after(1000,self.log)
```

Here is some sample output:

```
2017-06-16, 13:18:37, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:36, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:36, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:36, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:37, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:37, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:37, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:36, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:36, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:36, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:37, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:37, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:37, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:38, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:36, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:36, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:36, 0.001,
2017-06-16, 13:18:37, 0.001,
```

In the second column, clearly logging is happening more than once per second, and is not being returned in order of time.
Any explanation of `after()` would be helpful, and if I need to move it out of `log()`, or where to put it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using threads? `after` is not recursive. and will always execute items in order.

Comment: What is `INSERT` in the `self.screen.insert(INSERT, self.t)` call? If `self.screen` is a `list`, then the calling sequence for its `insert` method may be wrong.

Comment: I'm willing to bet `self.screen` is a tkinter text widget.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was infinity more simple than I made it (learned my lesson about posting to fast on overflow before fully investigating my own code). I wasn't reseting `self.t` to the empty string with every new call to `log()`. Thanks again for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this creating a recursion and therefore not returning the logs in order of time?

No. A better name for `after` would have been `add_job_to_queue`. It doesn't make a recursive call, it simply adds a function to a queue. Tkinter will periodically process that queue, pulling functions off and calling them.

After calling `self.log()` once, the queue will only ever have one item on it. When tkinter processes the queue it will pop the item off and run it. During the running, a new job is added to the queue. Then tkinter will pop that off the queue, and then a new one gets added. And so on. The queue never gets bigger than one.

The behavior you describe sounds like you are eotjer starting more than one "loop" of calling `self.log()`, and/or you're using threading.